# APK has native code but does not have x86 architecture. Switching device type to physical Nexus 5, aka "hammerhead". Please try again

Tags: android, android-studio, x86, apk, hammer

I'm trying to boot my apk in appetize.io, But I get the following error: "APK has native code but does not have x86 architecture. Switching device type to physical Nexus 5, aka" hammerhead. "Please try again."

I'm desperate, I've been trying to solve it for 4 hours ...

Comment: does the APK have x86 architecture?

Comment: Where can I look at that?

Comment: thanks for comment
I'm crying with rage

Comment: is it your app? If its your app post manifest, if its not your app, I'm not sure how to tell

Comment: Yes, in my gradle I included:

  splits {
      enable true

           
      reset ()
      include "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "mips"

      
      universalApk false
    }
  }

Comment: And I have uploaded the created x86 apk to http://appetize.io. But I get the error: APK has native code but does not have x86 architecture. Switching device type to physical Nexus 5, aka "hammerhead". Please try again.

Comment: post some of your code to help others answer the question

Comment: I do not have the code until tomorrow at work at 7:30 a.m. Tomorrow my boss wants me to show him the application, I am in Spain and he is in France. I want to teach the app remotely. Do you know any other portal to teach the app remotely? Thank you